# Inject a bean as a constructor argument in a child class

Tags: java, spring

How to inject a bean as a constructor argument in a child class when the parent class constructor takes a list of that type.

```
@Service
public class Parent{
    private List<MyObject> myObjectList;
    public Parent(List<MyObject> myObjectList){
        this.myObjectList = myObjectList;
    }
}

@Service
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Autowired
    public Child(MyObject myObject){
        super( ???? );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this ?

```
super(Arrays.asList(new MyObject[] {myObject}));
```

Comment: Even simplier: `super(Arrays.asList(myObject));`